# Android drawable resources for different aspect ratio

Tags: android, drawable, android-resources, aspect-ratio

Screen with resolution 240x320, 480x640, 1536x1152 ... has aspect ratio 0.75, screen with resolutions 480*800 has aspect ratio 0.6 etc.

I need use different resources for different aspect ratio.

Can I specify configuration folder to Android take an image by screen aspect ratio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify `long` and `notlong` for resources.

Refer to [Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

> long: Long screens, such as WQVGA, WVGA, FWVGA
>
> notlong: Not long screens, such as QVGA, HVGA, and VG

Comment: 240x320 - is a long or notlong?

Comment: 240x320 is QVGA. Refer to [Graphics display resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_display_resolution)